# Filling a vector<int>*

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I am learning C++ and I got a problem with this function. I originally passed the whole vector, then passed a pointer to the vector instead; however I cannot seem to assign values from a pointer to the vector.

```
void fill(std::vector<int> *vec, const int startVal)
{
    const int n = vec->size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        vec[i] = startVal + i
    }
}
```

How can I assign a value at the ith postion of the pointer (vec) to the vector?

I tried:

```
vec->[i] = startVal + i;
```

Comment: `(*vec)[i]` would work. But why pass a pointer? Pass a reference instead, or two iterators.

Comment: @juanchopanza: He might be following the [_Google C++ Style Guide_](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments) :) _"All parameters passed by reference must be labeled `const`."_

Comment: @Mr.C64 I had forgotten about that nonsense :-) I seriously hope nobody really follows that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you should pass the vector by reference:

```
void fill( std::vector<int> &vec, int startVal )
```

Then the line you want would be:

```
    vec[i] = startVal + i;
```

As you are using a pointer, you have to dereference the pointer, so:

```
    (*vec)[i] = startVal + i;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can de-reference the pointer like this:

```
(*vec)[i]
```

or

```
vec->operator[](i)
```

but you could make your life easier by passing a reference,

```
void fill(std::vector<int>& vec, int startVal)
```

or calling [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), which is a standard library algorithm that implements the functionality of your confusingly named `fill` function:

```
std::vector<int> v = ....;
....
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), startVal);
```

Comment: is there any way to use `iota` but to create the elements as you go, instead of assigning to default-constructed ones?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Unfortunately not. There's no way of specifying the end of the range other than passing an end iterator. It would be nice to have an `iota_n` type function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You could use generate_n but I don't know if it guarantees linear order.